# Table Type is not holding the data

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have defined an Object type without its body and table type having that object type to store data.

Now when I am calling a function and trying to store data into the table type and finally querying that table type. But in result I am not getting anything.

Defined:

Object: `Object_sample(KEYCODE varchar2(60))`

```
create or replace TYPE RESULTS_TABLE IS TABLE OF Object_sample;
```

Comment: Show us the code where  you use the type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats the common mistake mostly occur when we play with Object type.

 it will be better if you show the code but here is what you can check and rectify if you have not implemented.
when you define your function then at a very first step initialize your Object type with default constructor say

your_ref Type := **Object_sample();**